# Enterprise Architect: View the whole project's Subversion File History

Tags: svn, version-control, enterprise-architect, configuration-management

Is there a way to view the whole history of all the versioned packages in Enterprise architect? I am only familiar that you can view the file history for a selected package of interest

This would be useful to see a list of the latest versioned packages in the overall project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to view the whole history of all the versioned packages
>   in Enterprise architect?

Try `svn` command-line client or TortoiseSVN if you are on Windows. Subversion will help you view the history of changes made to certain files and projects. For example, run the command `svn log https://svn.example.com/repos/MyRepository/MyProject/trunk` and the client will display all changes that mere made on `/trunk` in `MyProject` project in `MyRepository` repository. Read more about viewing changes history in [SVNBook | Examining History](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.history.html) and [TortoiseSVN Manual | Revision Log Dialog](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html).

PS I'm not familiar with Enterprise Architect and I'm not sure about its version-control capabilities or user interface it offers.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a suitable subversion client and see what it can offer. EA isn't doing anything else than using a VC's API.